# Setting a number format pattern in iReport 5.7.0 to retain 3 digits after the decimal point

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using *iReport 5.7.0* to generate *JasperReports*'s report.
I have set the pattern #####0.000 on a field with a Double value.
I have expected 3 decimal places But actually Only one zero after the decimal point is displayed if the number has no decimal part .
i.e , what I get 
   `4.56678 =>4.566
   4.0 =>4.0
   4.1 => 4.000

What I want 
   4.5667888 =>4.566
   4.0 =>4.000
   4.1 =>4.000  `

Any help please ?

Comment: So it seems you saying it works for 4.56678 and 4.1 but it doesn't for 4.0. Is this correct?

Answer (score 4):

Try following at the place where you want a particular decimal format. Say you have a field into report, Total_Number:

```
new DecimalFormat("#0.000").format($F{Total_number})
```

If the value for $F{Total_number} is `4.5667888`. Following is the output:

**Output**

```
4.566
```

Comment: I dont have a problem with numbers with decimal part .Actually my problem is with numbers with no decimal part . I want 2 to be displayed as    2.000     . All I get is    2.0

Comment: Done , but I still get the same result

Comment: hii I was doing the same things from my side in my .jrxml file but its gives me :=>                                                                                             Failed to invoke method execute in class com.nantic.jasperreports.JasperServer: Error evaluating expression :
Source text : new DecimalFormat("#0.00").format($F{Quantity-                                        product_uom_qty})  Error when I will generate my report

Comment: And I am using iReport 4.0.2 tools for designing purpose of jrxml file